# KinectRegion does not exist in namespace "http://schemas.microsoft.com/kinect/2013"

Tags: wpf, xaml, kinect-sdk, kinect-interaction

This error message comes up when i try to build my app, but it still finds the KinectSensorChooserUI element. I'm using Kinect for Windows v1 sensor with SDK 1.8

```
<Window x:Class="Jump.Desktop.View.GameWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:k="http://schemas.microsoft.com/kinect/2013"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
        WindowStyle="None"
        ResizeMode="NoResize"
        WindowState="Maximized"
        Title="Jump" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="10" Grid.Row="0">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElapsedTime}"></TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
        <k:KinectSensorChooserUI HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Name="sensorChooserUi" />
        <k:KinectRegion x:Name="kinectRegion" Grid.Row="1">
            <Grid>

            </Grid>
        </k:KinectRegion>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this problem, you gotta download and install the Kinect Toolkit (this is after installing the SDK)

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40276

Then you've gotta add a reference to Microsoft.Kinect.Toolkit in your proyect, if you can't find it listed in the Assemblies tab, manually browse for it, it should be in this default location

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Kinect\Developer Toolkit v1.7.0\Assemblies

Answer (score 0):

actually you need to add Microsoft.Kinect.Toolkit.Controls